# Suppose $P(Y=y)=0$. Is $P(X=x|Y=y)$ a well defined object?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Consider two discrete random variables $X$ and $Y$ defined on the same probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$. Suppose $P(Y=y)=0$. Is $P(X=x|Y=y)$ a well defined object?

I would say that the answer is NO given the formula
$$
P(X=x|Y=y)=\frac{P(X=x, Y=y)}{P(Y=y)}
$$

However, I remember some definition of conditional probability using measure theory and I'm wondering whether that would give a different answer.

Comment: I would say not, providing $Y$ is a *discrete* random variable.  But perhaps you could pre-define it if you wished.  So for example you could have $Y=0 \text{ or } 1$ each with probability $\frac12$, and $P(X=y\mid Y=y) = \frac23$ and  $P(X=2y\mid Y=y) = \frac13$.  In that case, you might say $P(X=6\mid Y=3)=\frac13$ implying $P(X=6 , Y=3) =  P(X=6\mid Y=3)P(Y=3)=\frac13 \times 0 = 0$ as expected

Comment: @Henri I see your point.Thanks

Comment: @drhab: I guess, you meant intersection, not union.

Comment: @Ilya Ah.. yes, of course. I rewrote my comment now.

Comment: In my view it is better to practice the formula $P(A∣B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$ (instead of the quotient), Then $P(A∣B)$ is actually not determined if $P(B)=0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general conditional probabilities are only define almost everywhere. That is, if you have a joint probability measure $\mathsf P$ and $\mu$ is its first marginal (e.g. distribution of $X$ in your notation), then conditional distribution is any [stochastic kernel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_kernel) $\kappa$ satisfying
$$
  \mathsf P(A\times B) = \int_A \kappa(B|x)\mu(\mathrm dx) \tag{1}
$$
for all measurable sets $A,B$. Due to the integral in condition on $\kappa$, it is not uniquely defined when exists. Namely, if $\kappa$ solves $(1)$ and $\mu(x = x_0) = 0$, then by changing $\kappa$ on $x_0$ we still get the solution of $(1)$. In contrast, if $\mu(x = x_0) \neq 0$ we get from $(1)$:
$$
  \mathsf P(A\times B) = \kappa(B|x_0)\mu(x = x_0) \quad\implies\quad \kappa(B|x_0) = \frac{\mathsf P(A\times B)}{\mu(x = x_0)}.
$$
Thus, if $\mu(x = x_0) > 0$  then the conditional probability is uniquely defined, but otherwise it can take any value *at this particular point*, whereas *its average behavior must comply with* $(1)$. That is, for every single point of zero measure, we can assign any value we want, but we can't do it to all of them *at the same time*, since a union of this points may have a non-zero measure.

So, short answer to your question: this quantity is not uniquely defined, but you can in fact talk of probability conditioned on zero event. With caution.

Answer (score 1):

That IS the definition using measure theory; $P$ is a measure! The answer is NO, for the reason you have given.

Comment: But who forbids me to say e.g. that $P(X=x\mid Y=y)=\frac13$ when $P(Y=y)=0$? We do have $\frac13\times0=0$. Unfortunately I must go now, but I will come back later.

Comment: Yes, please, I'm interested in your argument. Thanks

Comment: The definition forbids you. The definition involves DIVISION, not simply the solving of a linear equation, $x \times 0 = 0$. The equation has solutions, but that is not the definition of conditional probability. $\frac 0 0$ is undefined.

Comment: @mathguy Thanks for your comment. However, here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability#As_an_axiom_of_probability it seems that the definition does not involve necessary division

Comment: What they show there is not a conditional probability. Here is an example: original probability space is the unit square, with "area" as the probability measure. If Y is entirely along the bottom side (the $[0,1]$ interval on the horizontal axis), then you can use "length" on the bottom segment and use "length" as the probability measure on that line segment. Take length ($X \cap Y$) divided by length($Y$) - but this is no longer related to the original, two-dimensional probability, so it is NOT a conditional probability with respect to it, it's something else.

Comment: In my view there is nothing against saying that $P(A\mid B)$ is by definition an element of $[0,1]$ such that $P(A\mid B)P(B)=P(A\cap B)$. In special case $P(B)=0$ we have the liberty to choose for a *suitable* value of $P(A\mid B)$. I will only drop this convenient definition is someone is able to show me that it causes trouble somewhere. (Sorry for my late reaction).